# Store results of unit test run into variables

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build configuration that builds a C# project, runs some unit tests, and then does some extra things. My question is: Can I get information about my unit test run stored into build configuration variables (i.e. how many tests were run, how many were successful, how many failed, how many were skipped) so that I can then check these variables in a PowerShell script in later build steps and perform different actions depending on how many tests have passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the best way is to ask these information directly to teamcity server using its [REST API](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/problemoccurrences.html)  (pay attention, maybe the build locator could be a little be tricly to be found, if the build is still running).

By other hand, you can parse your NUnit test result file (or file**s** if you run  more than one NUnit test runner step in your build) inside your build agent machine.